# How to exchange public_token between stripe and plaid

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, plaid

I have some code as below that exchanges token between stripe and plaid,
but my code throwing error as `bad public_token`.

I have use following Package from nugget in my application for plaid in C#

```
Install-Package Stripe-Plaid-Link
```

Library reference
https://github.com/asciutto990/Stripe-and-Plaid-Link-.NET

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PlaidAsync(string account_id, string public_token)
{
    var plaidApi = new PlaidApi();
    try
    {
        var response = await plaidApi.ExchangeTokenAsync(new ExchangeTokenInput
        {
            PublicToken = public_token,
            AccountId = account_id,
        });
        var bankToken = response.StripeBankAccountToken;
        var accountId = response.AccountId;
        var sandbox = response.Sandbox;
        var accessToken = response.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (PlaidException e)
    {
        var errorMessage = e.Message;               
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Plaid API V2 (sandbox), follow 6 steps given in Plaid Doc : https://plaid.com/docs/stripe/#step1

For step:3, add api version in call

```
apiVersion: 'v2',
```

On success of this event, call plaid API `https://sandbox.plaid.com/item/public_token/exchange` to get Access token.

After that call plaid API `https://sandbox.plaid.com/processor/stripe/bank_account_token/create` to get Bank account token

Another reference for APIs refer
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4675947/RWMLHkHR?version=latest#64d97a2b-071b-4826-838c-a8acec7d33ec